# Python, adb and shell execution query

Tags: python, adb

I don't have a lot of familiarity with Python but I do with Ruby. So I will provide analogues for what I want to achieve

In Ruby I would

```
val = `adb devices`
```

to get the "raw output" of adb devices stored in val, and

```
val=system("adb devices")
```

to get the status code

I want to perform the same tasks in Python. I looked at

```
from subprocess import call
call(["adb devices"])
```

but that failed, I don't want to use os.system cause I want to get some proper error handling. how do i make call work and how do i obtain raw output from backticks in Python

Comment: Never mind. I just did
`call(["adb", "devices"])` and it worked. However, I stil want to know how to get backticks output

Comment: Ruby note: If you use the backtick syntax (`\`adb devices\``), you can use `$?.exitstatus` to get the status code; no need for `system()`.

Comment: Thanks, I never knew that :)

Comment: it is `subprocess.check_output(['adb', 'devices'])` in Python (note: this command doesn't run the shell).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pass the command and arguments as separate elements of a list:

```
from subprocess import call
return_code = call(["adb", "devices"])
```

However, this sends the output to stdout and you can't capture it. Instead you can use [`subprocess.check_ouput()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output):

```
from subprocess import check_output

adb_ouput = check_output(["adb", "devices"])
# stdout of adb in adb_output.
```

If the return code is non-zero an exception is raised. You should catch it to see what the return code is. No exception is raised for return code 0:

```
from subprocess import check_output, CalledProcessError

try:
    adb_ouput = check_output(["adb", "devices"])
except CalledProcessError as e:
    print e.returncode
```