# subprocess.check_output fails to execute a command but the same works in windows

Tags: android, python, shell, subprocess, adb

I am trying to connect two devices to my pc and run some commands on them using python and adb.
when I run the command from the command prompt, it goes through fine, but when i put those in the python script, they give me errors.
this is causing the errors all the time:

```
from subprocess import check_output, CalledProcessError
try:
    adb_ouput = check_output(["adb","devices","-l","|", "grep", "\"model\""])
    print adb_ouput
except CalledProcessError as e:
    print e
```

The error message I get is this:

```
Usage: adb devices [-l]
Command '['adb', 'devices', '-l', '|', 'grep', '"model"']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

When I try the same code without the grep command, it works

```
adb_ouput = check_output(["adb","devices","-l"])
```

It gives me the right output.

When I try the same in windows command prompt, It works fine (I am replacing grep with FINDSTR  because i'm using it in windows, and I have tried doing the same in the python script as well, with 'shell = True' and also without.)

eg:

```
adb devices -l | FINDSTR "model"
```

This gives me an ouptut without any problems.
The output I get is

> 123ab6ef               device product:xxxxxxxxx model:xxxxxxxxx device:xxxxxxxxx
>
> bd00051a4     device product:yyyyyyyyyy model:yyyyyyyyyy device:yyyyyyyyy

I am trying to understand where I am going wrong here, but can't figure it out.
So far I have checked the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html
https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.CalledProcessError
These just give me the error codes.

I have also looked at these answers:
[Python, adb and shell execution query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27603586/python-adb-and-shell-execution-query)
I took some error checking from here and added to my code.

[Python subprocess.check_output(args) fails, while args executed via Windows command line work OK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28450572/python-subprocess-check-outputargs-fails-while-args-executed-via-windows-comm/28460506#28460506)
[python check_output fails with exit status 1 but Popen works for same command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28675138/python-check-output-fails-with-exit-status-1-but-popen-works-for-same-command)

I think i am close but just can't put my finger on it.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First

```
adb_ouput = check_output(["adb","devices","-l","|", "grep", "\"model\""])
```

certainly requires `shell=True`, but even with that it's not equivalent to

```
adb devices -l | FINDSTR "model"
```

When using `check_output`, you're passing `"model"` as `grep` argument literally but you should pass just `model`. `"model"` is not in your output (with quotes) so `grep` fails to find it, and returns exitcode `1` which is not really an error for `grep` but makes `check_output` trigger an exception because it expects `0`.

So I would to this as a quickfix:

```
adb_ouput = check_output(["adb","devices","-l","|", "grep", "model"],shell=True)
```

And as a longfix I'd perform the `grep` command directly with python.

```
adb_output = check_output(["adb","devices","-l"])
for l in adb_output.splitlines():
     if "model" in l:
         print(l)
```

Comment: I did try it without the quotes as well, but it fails.
I am sticking to filtering my output in python instead of using grep. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I don't understand why it doesn't work, but the second solution is better anyway. You could even imagine putting that on a machine that doesn't have `grep`.